# Add 3 ints on same inputed line

Tags: java

I got stuck yet again on a program.

```
 public int sumNumber(int a , int b, int c)
{
 int line = a+b+c;
 return line;
 }
public int sumNumber (int b , int c )
{

    int total = b +c;


    return total;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    Assignment12 a12 = new Assignment12();
    int y = a12.sumNumber(1, 2, 3);
    System.out.println("Enter two three-digit numbers");
    int num1 = in.nextInt(y),     num2 = in.nextInt(y);
    int  x = a12.sumNumber(0, 1);

    System.out.println("The sum of the digits is : "+ y );
```

I want to add the numbers I inputted then add the second set.
what the output should look like is:

```
Enter two three-digit numbers
  521
  412
  sum  = 15
```

To Clarify whats happening:

```
Enter 2 three digit numbers
 5+2+1 = 8
 4+1+2 = 7
then it adds 8 and 7

 sum = 15
```

I overloaded on purpose.....plus can you guys keep it simple as possible(I'm still learning)

Comment: Well, there's different ways to go about this. If you take them as integers, look into how `%` can help. If you take them as strings then look at `split()`-ing them, parsing, and adding them together.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Do you have a visual maybe....Sorry I'm a visual learner =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Two Method instead of one

- one for Number Digits Sum
- Second one for Number Sum

Digits Sum--

```
public int digitSum(int a)
{
     int sum=0;
     while(a!=0)       //while(a)
    {
       sum += a%10;
       a /= 10;
     }
    return sum;
 }
```

Number Sum

```
public int sum(int a,int b)
{
    // You can Get Digits Sum Here or Before any Where by just calling above method

 return digitSum(a)+digitSum(b); 
}
```

Comment: Please indent and format your code properly and fix the compile error at `while (a)`—this is Java, not C. And please don’t call your method `sum` when it really computes the _digit sum_, as this is confusing.

Comment: i already mention in sum as comment that you can use digitSum method as per interest. or you may change function name as you want or merge both method.

Comment: and about while(a) it should be understood for a programmer,i am writing just a basic implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can modify your functions this way:

```
public int sumNumber (int b , int c )
{   
       int sum =0;

       while(b!=0){
            sum += b%10;
            b = b/10;
         }
       b =sum;

       while(c!=0){
           sum += c%10;
           c = c/10;
         }

       c= sum;

        int total = b +c;


       return total;
```

}

I am not sure about your requirement for this class. But you can define a function like this:

```
int digitSum(int x){

             int sum=0;

           while(x!=0){
                sum += x%10;
                x = x/10;
             }

       return sum;
 }
```

You can just call this function it will give you the sum of all the digits .